# Select CASE statement error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a SELECT CASE statement that I am trying to get working. Essentially i want to query for specific group numbers in our DBase and show the respective information with an include file.  I am getting an error, but am unable to diagnose what is actually causing the error...

Is my statement not structured correctly?

```
<% 
            select case session("memGroup")
            case "123456789","987654321"
            'Show forms for Company ABC
        %>

            <!--#include virtual="/members/_includes/formsABC.asp"-->

        <%             
            case "333333333","22222222","111111111" 
            'Show forms for Company DEF
        %>

            <!--#include virtual="/members/_includes/formsDEF.asp"-->

        <%
          end select
        %>
<!--then show forms for everyone else-->

<!--#include virtual="/members/_includes/formsEveryoneElse.asp"-->
```

Comment: You've tagged your question `sql`, but it looks like...VBScript?

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: nothing...just says HTTP 50 internal server error...

Comment: you need to enable descriptive errors, and see what it says.
One thing to note is that the includes will be added to the code, all of them, even if they're inside a 'case' or in an 'if'. This can be important because if in formsABC you have a 'dim a' and in formsDEF you have a 'dim a' you'll get a duplicate definition error

Comment: Could you please specify the languages and environment you're using, it sure doesn't seem like VB.

Comment: @Lance Roberts this is VBScript, which is a subset of VB6, not VB.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP will process all the includes first, so this is not the best way of doing this as includes are expensive, I would do something like this instead:

```
<% 
    Select Case Session.Contents("memGroup")
        Case "123456789", "987654321":
            'Show forms for Company ABC
            Server.Execute("/members/_includes/formsABC.asp")
        Case "333333333", "22222222", "111111111":
            'Show forms for Company DEF
            Server.Execute("/members/_includes/formsDEF.asp")
        Case Else:
            Server.Execute("/members/_includes/formsEveryoneElse.asp")
    End Select
%>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849(v=vs.90).aspx 
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134119/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022504-1.shtml

As a side note if the web server is running IIS 7 or greater you will need to change web.config to see ASP error messages:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/> 
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also you will need to turn off "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages" in Internet Explorer or use another browser to view the error.

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-a-500-internal-server-error-for-all-asp-errors.html